# How do I use scp to copy a file from the server to the client side ?

Tags: terminal, command-line-arguments, scp

How do I transfer files from a computer I am accessing remotely back to the computer I'm currently at?

Can anyone help me?

Here's the syntax I know so far,

scp (filename) (I don't know what to put here): (location on my computer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your computer is Internet accessible, this - hacky as it is - should work;

```
scp (filename) `echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}'`:(location on my computer)
```

The easier way (that will always work) is to *do the scp from a new window on your local computer instead*;

```
scp (remote computer):path/to/remote/file (location on my local computer)
```

`remote computer` being the same address you normally ssh to.

As an example, if the file is on the remote computer called `remotecomputer.com` in a subdirectory of your home directory called `important` and the file is called `test.txt`, you can issue this command on the local computer to copy it to the current directory on the local computer;

```
scp remotecomputer.com:important/test.txt .
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the path though. For some reason, it just won't work.

Comment: How do I find out what to put in the bubble, (local computer)?

Comment: Well, the problem is I'm not sure how to do the pathing. I've tried something like /home/usernamefolder/(myfile) but it can't find the darn file for some reason. Where do you start from when you do paths?

Comment: Is there a way I can find the address of my local computer that I'm connecting to the remote computer from?

Comment: @Mechy `echo $SSH_CLIENT` on the remote computer.

Comment: That's great! Do I just put my own username before that?

e.g. Mechy@(ipaddress)

Comment: @Mechy Then your local computer either does not run an SSH server or there's a firewall or NAT router involved. Either means doing scp from your local machine is the only option.

Comment: How do I figure out the path for where my file is? I keep trying, but it tells me that it can't find the file. Is there a command I can type  to figure out the path to the file? Thanks for the help so far by the way.

Comment: @Mechy Go to the directory where the file is and type `pwd`, that will tell you the path you need to use. Just add the file name at the end and you'll have the absolute path of the file.

Comment: @Mechy If you're logging into the remote server using public-key authentication (passwordless login) you can do tab-completion in the same way as you would in a normal `bash` session.  I find this very helpful as it means I don't have to create an `ssh` session just to copy the path.

Comment: I figured it out. When I did scp (host):(I put space here)/address That was the problem.

Comment: Without ssh server on your computer and router port forwarded to your ssh server or DMZ ip exposure, this will not work.

Answer (score 12):

scp is actually easier to use than appears at first glance.

`scp <from> <to>`

`<from>` or `<to>` can be local or remote.

Remote files are of the form `user@host:path_on_remote`

Local files are just simple paths: `/path/to/my/file.txt`

If you are doing this by hand, you might find it easier not to copy the file *back* to your office machine, by running the following from the localhost *before* being logged into the remote host:

`scp user@remotehost:/path/to/my/file/on/remote.txt /local/path/local.txt`

If you need to copy a directory - as has already been mentioned - you can give scp the `-r` option.

When logged into a remote, copying back is basically the same, though you'll need ssh running on your local machine, which may require port-fowarding on your local router.  I tend to find it easier calling `scp` on my laptop to the server rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

with pem file(pem file need to located in root)

```
$ scp -i <pem.pem> <file_on_local> <user>@<remotehost>:/path/to/file
```

with credentials

```
$ scp <file_on_local> <user>@<remotehost>:/path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp), `man scp`...

`scp file_on_local user@host.name:/path/to/file`

If you add a `-r`, it can do a whole dir.